# How to set line-height of selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

Trying to shrink the height of select picker by adjusting the `line-height`. However, I don't know how to access the select picker button to shrink the line height because it gets generated dynamically. This is the code:

```
<select id="views" class="form-control selectpicker " >
    <option> Sample </option>
</select>
```

If I look at inspect element I can see the button to assign the line height:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="views" title="all" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">all</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
</div>
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADyR0.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIXZW.png)

Comment: Can you not add some css? `.selectpicker { line-height: 20px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to apply the following css

```
#view_group .btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-default{
line-height: 10px
}
```

This targets the button from the selectpicker within a specific div so that it doesn't get applied to all selectpickers

Comment: #view_group means the <select> id?